# Is there a function in Excel which display the same cell value (e.g. client name) several times (as mentioned in another cell)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Please refer to the picture. I would like to have one formula in the red marked cell (I4) which I can drag-down. I tried several formulas (like ADDRESS, INDIRECT or OFFSET) to kind of work with an array.

I tried the follwoing so far:

In cell I4 I made just the reference to the client name:

```
=Sheet1!A4
```

In cell I5 I started working on the formula:

```
=IF(Sheet1!D4-COUNTA($I$4:I4)>0;I4;ADDRESS(4+(Sheet1!D4-COUNTA($I$4:I4));1;1;FALSE;"Sheet1"))
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can be easily achieved with a few helper columns, INDEX and MATCH formulas.

First helper, is a 'First Row' column, in column E (next to your Sum column). In cell E4 add `=D4+N(E3)` and drag this down for all your Client/Service rows

Then on Sheet2, add a 2nd helper column (Client Row) between your Row column and your Client columns. If Row 1 is in cell A4 on Sheet2, then put `=IFERROR(MATCH(A4-1,Sheet1!$E$4:$E$6,1)+1,1)` in cell B4, and then drag down.

For your Client column, in cell C4 put `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$6,B4)` and drag down.

Then when you change your values in your service columns the data on Sheet2 will update. I've assumed that if a client has zero services on Sheet1 you don't want them to appear on Sheet2, so for example if you make Client B 0 for service1 and service2 the your Sheet2 list will just show Client A and C, but with errors after the last client C row. Some error handling can be built into the formulas to deal with this if you want.

Answer (score 0):

There should be other/easier ways to do it. But this is my approach.

*Suggestion:* Solve this kind of problems by breaking them in smaller steps.

**Setup:**

[image: Setup]

**Formulas per column:**

How many times (previous cell): `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(H3;$A$4:$B$6;2;FALSE);0)`

Count appearances in result (previous cell): `=COUNTIF(H$3:H3;H3)+1`

Find changes: `=IF(E4-D4>0;1;0)`

Sum changes: `=SUM(F$3:F3)`

Result: `=IF(IF(F4=1;OFFSET($A$4;G4;0);H3)<>0;IF(F4=1;OFFSET($A$4;G4;0);H3);"")`

Drag the formulas down

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet2 I4, formula copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(ROW(Sheet1!A1),SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$3,,,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4)))+1,Sheet1!A$4:A$6)&""
```

[image]